# .SaveAs will rename newly created Worksheet but won't actually save it Excel VBA

Tags: excel, vba

I am putting together a VBA macro for Excel that will create and save a new workbook, with the name of workbook based on the value of cells in a different workbook. Going through the code line by line, it appears that the code is correctly assigning the path of the new file, and is correctly assigning the name of the file, but it just won't actually save it. I will add on that when I go to the file details on "File" tab in Excel after it tries to save, it has the correct file path listed under the "Info" section, it just doesn't actually save there.

When I step through it, the new workbook is created, renamed, but then I get an error for "Method 'SaveAs' of object '_Workbook failed". I've tried creating the workbook on one line then doing a Save As on another, but I get the same error with the .SaveAs line being highlighted. I tried to save the file manually after it was renamed, and it popped up saying that there were errors with saving and that it can try to recover the file.

```
    currMonth = Format(Date, "mmmm")
    
    currYear = Format(Date, "yyyy")
    
    currDate = Format(Date, "mm-dd-yy")

    workloadFile = Dir(workloadFileName)
    
    newFilePath = "\\prometheus\HF-MFS\HEDGEGRP\Centralized_Recon\Ares\Jawn\AGED BREAK REVIEW\" & currMonth & " " & currYear & "\Week of " & currDate & "\"
    
    lastEmp = Workbooks(workloadFile).Sheets("Sheet2").Cells(Workbooks(workloadFile).Sheets("Sheet2").Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
    
    lastTran = Workbooks(currRecon).Sheets("All Breaks-Custody").Cells(Workbooks(currRecon).Sheets("All Breaks-Custody").Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
    
    empStart = "A2"
    
    Set empRange = Workbooks(workloadFile).Sheets("Sheet2").Range(empStart & ":A" & lastEmp)
    
    empName = Workbooks(workloadFile).Sheets("Sheet2").Range(empStart).Value
    
    newFileName = empName & currDate & ".xlsx"
        
    Workbooks.Add.SaveAs Filename:=newFilePath & newFileName
```

Comment: A worksheet or a workbook?

Comment: Sorry, its a workbook. Regarding the newFileName variable, the Name ends up being something like "John 02-12-24".

Comment: Do all of the folders in the path already exist?  If not then you will need to create them before saving the workbook.

Comment: Correct, the folder does exist.